# Rebooting or (Stopping and Starting) an EC2 instance makes it impossible to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, vps

I have launched 5 or 6 EC2 instances and **every time I reboot one or (stop and start it)** using the **AWS console** (Not with the Command Line), I find myself unable to connect to it.
When I try to connect using `ssh`, this is what gets logged:

> ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com
> port 22: Connection timed out

And when I use the AWS console to try to connect on the browser, this is what I see:
[image]

I have waited hours after restarting and still the same result and this happens with every single instance and every time I reboot it or stop and restart it.

This is deeply frustrating and there seems to be no answer on the internet.

Comment: Are you using the public IP of the instance to connect to it? Have you checked if the IP is the same?

Comment: Stopping and starting an instance will cause the public IP and public DNS to change, unless you have assigned an Elastic IP to it. However rebooting will not cause the IP to change.

Comment: Good to know. However, even when I used the AWS console, it was still unable to connect. And somehow later on, I was able to connect. No idea why.

Comment: `ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out` 
How about security inbound rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for some time after reboot to connect to instance again.